# Python: How to return values in a multiprocessing situation?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Let's say I have a collection of `Process`-es, `a[0]` through `a[m]`.

These processes will then send a job, via a queue, to another collection of `Process`-es, `b[0]` through `b[n]`, where `m > n`

Or, to diagram:

```
a[0], a[1], ..., a[m] ---Queue---> b[0], b[1], ..., b[n]
```

Now, how do I return the result of the `b` processes to the relevant `a` process?

My first guess was using `multiprocessing.Pipe()`

So, I've tried doing the following:

```
## On the 'a' side
pipe = multiprocessing.Pipe()
job['pipe'] = pipe
queue.put(job)
rslt = pipe[0].recv()

## On the 'b' side
job = queue.get()
... process the job ...
pipe = job['pipe']
pipe.send(result)
```

and it doesn't work with the error: `Required argument 'handle' (pos 1) not found`

Reading many docs, I came up with:

```
## On the 'a' side
pipe = multiprocessing.Pipe()
job['pipe'] = multiprocessing.reduction.reduce_connection(pipe[1])
queue.put(job)
rslt = pipe[0].recv()

## On the 'b' side
job = queue.get()
... process the job ...
pipe = multiprocessing.reduction.rebuild_connection(job['pipe'], True, True)
pipe.send(result)
```

Now I get a different error: `ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack`.

I've tried searching and searching and still can't find how to properly use the `reduce_` and `rebuild_` methods.

Please help so I can return the value from `b` to `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to avoid using this movement of Pipe and file descriptors (last time I tried, it was not very standard and not very well documented). Having to deal with it was a pain, I do not recommend it :-/

I would suggest a different approach: let the `main` manage the connections. Keep a work queue, but sent the responses in a different path. This means that you need some kind of identifier for the threads. I will provide a toy implementation to illustrate my proposal:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import multiprocessing
import random

def fib(n):
    "Slow fibonacci implementation because why not"
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)


def process_b(queue_in, queue_out):
    print "Starting process B"
    while True:
        j = queue_in.get()
        print "Job: %d" % j["val"]
        j["result"] = fib(j["val"])
        queue_out.put(j)


def process_a(index, pipe_end, queue):
    print "Starting process A"
    value = random.randint(5, 50)
    j = {
        "a_id": index,
        "val": value,
    }

    queue.put(j)
    r = pipe_end.recv()

    print "Process A sent value %d and received: %s" % (value, r)


def main():
    print "Starting main"

    a_pipes = list()
    jobs = multiprocessing.Queue()
    done_jobs = multiprocessing.Queue()

    for i in range(5):
        multiprocessing.Process(target=process_b, args=(jobs, done_jobs,)).start()

    for i in range(10):
        receiver, sender = multiprocessing.Pipe(duplex=False)
        a_pipes.append(sender)
        multiprocessing.Process(target=process_a, args=(i, receiver, jobs)).start()

    while True:
        j = done_jobs.get()
        a_pipes[j["a_id"]].send(j["result"])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Note that the Queue of jobs is connected directly between `a` and `b` processes. `a` process is responsible to put their identifier (which the "master" should know). The `b` uses a different Queue for finished work. I used the same job dictionary, but typical implementation should use some more tailored data structure. This response should have the identifier of `a` in order for the master to send that to the specific process.

I assume that there is some way to use it with your approach, which I don't dislike at all (it would have been my first approach). But having to deal with file descriptors and the `reduce_` and `rebuild_` methods is not nice. Not at all.

Comment: Yeah, I've practically given up. Too much work, not enough documentation, and worst of all: The code starts to look like spaghetti code. I'm going to post my final workaround, but I'll mark yours as the answer.

Comment: @pepoluan Appreciate that. Using *Proxy and multiprocessing Managers crossed my mind, but I have yet to use them a little more. I tend to come up with some more low-level strategies. The DictProxy is indeed a clean alternative.

Answer (score 1):

So, as @MariusSiuram explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34990967/149900), trying to pass a `Connection` object is an exercise in frustration.

I finally resorted to using a `DictProxy` to return values from `B` to `A`.

This is the concept:

```
### This is in the main process
...
jobs_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
ret_dict = manager.dict()
...
# Somewhere during Process initialization, jobs_queue and ret_dict got passed to
# the workers' constructor
...

### This is in the "A" (left-side) workers
...
self.ret_dict.pop(self.pid, None)  # Remove our identifier if exist
self.jobs_queue.put({
    'request': parameters_to_be_used_by_B,
    'requester': self.pid
})
while self.pid not in self.ret_dict:
    time.sleep(0.1)  # Or any sane value
result = self.ret_dict[self.pid]    
...

### This is in the "B" (right-side) workers
...
while True:
    job = self.jobs_queue.get()
    if job is None:
        break
    result = self.do_something(job['request'])
    self.ret_dict[job['requester']] = result
...
```